# How to check whether all valid values entered to my program will be correctly calculated?

Tags: java

I created a same sized - stack based simple calculator for adding 2 operands. I want to know whether my addition becomes incorrect when specific (*valid*) values are entered. The 2 stacks take integer values and are having the same number of digits (i.e. 400 *[3 digits]* and 900 *[3 digits]*).

Comment: I didn't add the code as it is too long and has 2 classes.

Comment: With the current information it's probably impossible to give you any specific answer. If your code is (too) long, then extract / reduce / focus your problem/question to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include it in your question. – Also note that _I want to know whether my addition becomes incorrect when specific (valid) values are entered._ is very vague – you would need to explain that in more detail; especially what "incorrect" means from your point of view (and based on your code ➜ MCVE).

Comment: @IvoMori Noted. I will do that in future questions, as I got the answer to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the algorithm you're using. From the question it is not clear, but let's assume your calculator can perform basic arithmetic. First off, you want to test each operation separately, because they have different equivalence classes of their inputs. For example, for multiplication it would be: 0, 1, minimum and maximum values, and their negations. Testing almost always will not be exhaustive, but using equivalence classes, you can pick one value from each class to make sure that each class is covered with a test.
Back to your question, you may use min/max values, and anything that you think may break your code.

Comment: I'll try that. My algorithm just does basic addition, I added that to the question, and thanks.